# What's the recommended strategy for Git 'Master' branch in Salesforce?

Tags: git, developer-productivity

I want to know the recommended strategy for maintaining the Git 'Master' branch. I would like to share two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** Our team is offered to work for a new client. The client has a pre-developed Salesforce environment. Our developed team requires adding some extra features. So, as usual, we created a new repo named 'SF-X.'

**Question 1:** So, the question is, what 'SF-X' repo's 'Master' branch will contain?

**My assumption for 1:** 'Master' branch will contain replicating the client's pre-developed codes.

---

**Scenario 2:** Our team is offered to work for a new client. The client wants us to develop some features from scratch in Salesforce. This means no code base exists. So, as usual, we created a new repo named 'SF-X.'

**Question 2:** So, the question is, what 'SF-X' repo's 'Master' branch will contain?

**My assumption for 2:** 'Master' branch will contain the Salesforce Development template (When we create a project using VSCode).

Please provide your valuable input for both of the questions. Thank you.

Comment: This question doesn't actually fall under SFSE scope and might most likely get closed, but both your assumptions are correct. Master branch should created first and SF-X should be a clone from master.

Comment: Hello @arut thanks for the reply. Could you please clarify your comment a bit more? Here SF-X is the repository name, it's the initial repository after starting the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the question is, what 'SF-X' repo's 'Master' branch will contain?

It depends. You have at least three choices.

First, you can choose to use git's "submodule" system, where the original repo is referenced by the new one. You can independently update both the SF-X repo and the parent repo independently and keep things in sync. This works well if your parent repo doesn't share a lot of similar file names (e.g, you're building an entirely new part of an application). The downside is that commits to the submodule will belong to the parent repo.

Second, you can choose to use the "fork" feature found in many git repos. This has the advantage that you can pull updates from the parent repo as if it were an upstream branch, and you can make "pull requests" to update from your repo to the parent repo. This has the advantage of being able to receive updates from the parent and also push things back to the parent if you want to.

Third, you can choose to just copy the repo. The easiest way to do this is to clone the repo, delete the .git folder entirely (`rm -rf .git`), then initialize a new git repository (`git init`). Note that if you do this, your clone loses all association to the parent repo. You can no longer make pull requests or receive fully merged updates from the parent repo. Consider this option carefully if you decide to go this route.

> So, the question is, what 'SF-X' repo's 'Master' branch will contain?

It will initially just contain the boilerplate setup, but you'll likely want to customize it to suit your needs by adding whatever extensions, npm modules, etc that you use to make your work more efficient. You may also find features you find annoying, and may turn off some of them.

Note that because of changing US culture, you may want to consider not naming your "master" branch "master", but instead "main" or something like that. Using "master" risks offending your U.S. clients, but "main" should be perfectly neutral around the world.